# Applying word embedding function on a large pandas dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp, word-embedding

We have a pandas dataframe with one column ('message') and 3.9 million rows and need to convert these messages to their word embeddings using Google's Universal Sentence encoder.

We tried the following options but got the following issues

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_hub as hub

url = 'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4'
embed = hub.load(url)

def __return_embedding(entry):
  return embed([entry])[0].numpy().tolist()

csv_files = [csvfile for csvfile in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if csvfile.endswith("." + 'csv')]
csvs = [pd.read_csv(f'{os.getcwd()}/{csv}', low_memory=False) for csv in csv_files]
dataframe = pd.concat(csvs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

embeddings = __return_embedding(dataframe.message) # this says InvalidArgumentError:  input must be a vector, got shape: [1,3900000]

dataframe['embedding'] = np.vectorize(__return_embedding)(dataframe['message']) # This one blows up the RAM on google colab and it crashes.
```

Does someone have a better way to get this done ?

Comment: If the second solution blows up the RAM, what about separating the data into smaller chunks and processing them one by one?

Comment: Trying that, one dataframe is also causing the blowup, trying smaller chunksize now..

Comment: Using chunking also blowsup the memory.